# Django with django-filer on a virtualenv fails

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm using `django 1.5.1` with `django-filer 0.9.3` package in order to handle images files with `FilerImageField`.

I use a `virtualenv` environment.

When I run my django web-app with `python manage.py runserver` (of course after a fresh `syncdb`), and I go to the web-app in my chrome browser, I select the FilerImageField and it fails with the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/filer/folder/
'adminmedia' is not a valid tag library: Template library adminmedia not found, tried django.templatetags.adminmedia,...

Error during template rendering

In template c:\temp\hc-sofware\venv\lib\site-packages\filer\templates\admin\filer\folder\directory_listing.html, error at line 2
'adminmedia' is not a valid tag library: Template library adminmedia not found, tried django.templatetags.adminmedia,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.adminmedia,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.adminmedia,filer.templatetags.adminmedia,easy_thumbnails.templatetags.adminmedia
{% extends "admin/filer/base_site.html" %}
{% load adminmedia filer_admin_tags filermedia i18n %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
{# upload stuff #}
{{ media.js }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_js_base %}jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% filer_staticmedia_prefix %}js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% filer_staticmedia_prefix %}js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% filer_staticmedia_prefix %}js/fileuploader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_js_base %}admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
```

**The strange thing is that without using virtualenv it works.**

Any clue you might have will be really helpful.

**Edit 1: settings.py**

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'hc',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails'
)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-filer` is not compatible with django 1.5 as stated in the [documentation](http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#dependencies).

Comment: Do'h. I thought pip install django-filer would handle this scenario for me (or at least a not-compatible error!)